# Python постоянно выдаёт ошибки

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

бота на питон с помощью телебот и у меня тут вот такой вот список ошибок.
Всё ошибки на фото (синий текст):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я уже так с ними намучался, 2 раза переустанавливал Питон, 1 раз среду разработки и уже 5 раз эту долбаную библиотеку телебот, помогите пожалуйста!!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Столько ошибок при том что код всего на 7 строчек.
!

Comment: Ошибка там всего одна. Означает она что более одного бота с одним токеном пытаются полить сервер.

Comment: Я предполагал что она именно это и значит, на ваш взгляд что следует сделать что-бы её устранить ?

Answer (score 1):

Судя по тексту ошибки Телега ругается что ты пытаешься получить доступ к боту к который уже запущен так что проверь не пытаешься ли ты получить доступ к боту с двух программ сам с этой ошибкой не раз сталкивался когда забывал закрыть консоль после предыдущего запуска

Comment: Окей посмотрю спасибо что ответили !