# Как исправить 409 conflict ошибку телграм бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Вот полная версия ошибки на скрине Полная версия.

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\python\telebot\util.py", line 59, in run task(*args, **kwargs)
> File "D:\python\telebot\__init__.py", line 158, in __retrieve_updates
>   updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id +     1), timeout=timeout)
> File "D:\python\telebot\__init__.py", line 128, in  get_updates
>   json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, offset, limit, timeout, allowed_updates)
> File "D:\python\telebot\apihelper.py", line 180, in get_updates
>   return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)
> File "D:\python\telebot\apihelper.py", line 56, in _make_request
>   return _check_result(method_name, result)['result']
> File "D:\python\telebot\apihelper.py", line 75, in _check_result
>   raise ApiException(msg, method_name, result)
>   telebot.apihelper.ApiException: A request to the        
>   Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 409 Conflict. 
>   Response body:
>     [b'{"ok":false,"error_code":409,"description":"Conflict:  
>     terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running"}']
> 2018-07-14 17:15:56,933 (__init__.py:299 MainThread)    
>   ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. 
>   The server returned HTTP 409 Conflict.           
>   Response body:
>   [b'{"ok":false,"error_code":409,"description":"Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates 
>   request; make sure that only one bot instance is running"}']"
> 2018-07-14 17:16:00,833 (util.py:65 PollingThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "ApiException occurred, 
>   args=('A request   to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned    
>   HTTP 409 Conflict. 
>   Response body:
>   \n[b\'{"ok":false,"error_code":409,"description":"Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates 
>   request; make sure that only one bot instance is running"}\']',)
> ```

Я спрашивал говорят, что эта ошибка означает попытку запуска бота с двух клиентов, но как её решить, ведь я запускаю только с одного с PyCharm
и только одну версию бота !

Comment: Вы ведь такой же вопрос уже задавали https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/855733/ . Похоже вы используйте токен от другого бота либо  забыли завершить другой процесс бота. Если вы и вправду используйте токен другого бота, то создайте нового бота через BotFather и его токен используйте для запуска вашего кода